# Is there a way to append a MATLAB struct saved in a file without loading it in to memory?

Tags: matlab

Say I have a 50x1 struct saved in myfile.mat. Is there a way to append it, so that I get a 51x1 struct in myfile.mat without actually having to load the whole 50x1 structure to memory?

Comment: You can try using `fid = fopen('foo.mat','a');` and `fwrite(fid,foobar)` but I'm not sure if it will preserve the structures in the `.mat` file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `matfile` to access the .mat file.  See the example ["Save to and Load from Part of a Variable."](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html#bt19yqz-1) Take your file, "myfile.mat".

Make a test file:

```
y = repmat(struct('field1',[],'field2',''),50,1);
save -v7.3 myfile.mat y
```

Note that [it is necessary to save with the `-v7.3` option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html#inputarg_filename) to allow partial loading of a variable:

> `matfile` only supports efficient partial loading and saving for MAT-files in Version 7.3 format. If you index into a variable in a Version 7 (the current default) or earlier MAT-file, MATLAB warns and temporarily loads the entire contents of the variable.

Load it with `matfile` and set it as writable:

```
m = matfile('myfile.mat','Writable',true);
```

To append an element to the existing 50x1 struct, `y`, in myfile.mat:

```
m.y(end+1,1) = m.y(end,1)
```

Here we're copying the last struct element, but to make a fresh one just use the same fields as in the rest of the struct array.

NOTE: `matfile` does not support indexing in to *fields* of struct arrays.  You can only do the above since it is a *non-scalar* struct array that is being indexed, not an individual field.